# HTML Canvas globalCompositeOperation without affecting previous layers

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have these 4 `layers`.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is put the `red` and `blue` layer into one `mask`. But I don't want the `purple` or `orange` layer to be affected by this mask (only the `red` and `blue`). I manage to make it work for the `orange` but not for the `purple` layer

See my code

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.height = window.innerHeight
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


//this should'nt be affected by the mask
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
ctx.rect(0, 50, 100, 100);
ctx.fill()

//this is the mask
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.rect(10, 10, 70, 70);
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill()

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';

//this need to be inside the mask
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
ctx.fill()

//this need to be inside the mask
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.rect(50, 40, 100, 100);
ctx.fill()


ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over'; //reset

//this should'nt be affected by the mask
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
ctx.rect(200, 40, 100, 100);
ctx.fill()
```

And the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ws3b4q95/4/

Answer (score 2):

`Canvas` doesn't know about shapes as objects, it only cares about pixels. So the purple rectangle can't be excluded from your mask, because *everyting that's already drawn on the canvas, will be part of the mask.*

Instead you should draw the rectangle after you've applied the mask, and use `destination-over` operation:

```
//this need to be inside the mask
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.rect(50, 40, 100, 100);
ctx.fill()

//this should'nt be affected by the mask
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = 'purple';
ctx.rect(0, 40, 100, 100);
ctx.fill()
```

This is nice summary from Mozilla about composite operations: [MDN web docs: CanvasRenderingContext2D.global .CompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation)